# Bulid.war File Using Different application.properties files (Maven) in intelij IDEA

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have a different **application.properties** file for Different Environment (**Dev,QA,Prod**)

[image: application.properties]

Is there any setting/way to use this **Quick access menu**

[image]

Without using **Maven command line**

Comment: Don't. You don't want to repackage the application for each environment. This basically means you are promoting untested artifacts to different environments. Instead specify through Spring using `spring.profiles.active=<env>` which should be loaded.

Comment: thanks spring.profiles.active=<env> works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We Can Change the content of `aplication.properties` file as below

aplication.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

aplication-dev.properties

```
 #DEV
 spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/db-dev?useSSL=false
 spring.datasource.username=root
 spring.datasource.password=root
 .......
```

aplication-qa.properties

```
#QA
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/db-qa?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
.......
```

aplication-prod.properties

```
 #PROD
 spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/db-prod?useSSL=false
 spring.datasource.username=root
 spring.datasource.password=root
 .......
```

This will Fix the above issue

Comment: application.properties file will re direct to specified properties file